# Errors when executing SQL Server SSIS Package From Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I have an SSIS package stored in the file system, that imports Paradox (.dbf) files.   The pacakge runs fine in BIDS, but errors out when I try to call it from the stored procedure.

I use the following syntax to call it from the sp

```
SET @packageString = 'dtexec /f [Packagename].dtsx  /Set \package.variables[ActivityDate].Value;"' + convert(VARCHAR(20),@dateTo, 101) + '"'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @packageString
```

This is the error I get:

> Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDB_NOPROVIDER_64BIT_ERROR.  The
>   requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not registered --
>   perhaps no 64-bit provider is available.  Error code: 0x00000000. An
>   OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service
>   Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".

I know the problem is with dbf files, because when I disable that task in SSIS, the rest of the package executes fine.
It looks like this package needs to run in 32-bit mode, but I can't figure out how to do it here.  Help, please!

Comment: Can you run the SSIS package via a scheduled job, or does it have to run when a user initiates an action?

Comment: It has to be run by a user from the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the solution!  Might not be the most elegant one, but it works.  For some reason, the double quotes were getting in the way.  So I got rid of them alltogehter:

```
SET @packageString = 'D:Progra~1\Micros~2\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe /f [Packagename].dtsx /Set \package.variables[ActivityDate].Value;"' + convert(VARCHAR(20),@dateTo, 101) + '"'
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two dtexec's available on 64bit machines. The windows Path variable has the 64bit Microsoft SQL Server listed first so you are invoking 64bit dtexec when you run it in the agent.  When you execute it from within BIDS, you are always using the 32bit version.

Update your variable to explicitly use the 32bit version of the exe like (Edit based on comments in [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) one needs to double up all their double quotes)

```
SET @packageString = '""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe"" /f [Packagename].dtsx  /Set \package.variables[ActivityDate].Value;"' + convert(VARCHAR(20),@dateTo, 101) + '"'
```

This assumes 2008 but if you had 2005 the above would replace the 100 with 90

Comment: Tried this, got the following error: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.  The path is in double quotes, but it doesn't seem to like the spaces in the path anyway..

Comment: Updated my answer, seems like the double quotes needed to be doubled up as xp_cmdshell was eating them

Comment: I am on 2008.  Now I am getting "The system cannot find the path specified" error, even though I can navigate to both DTEXEC.exe and dts packages files..

Comment: That error is most likely due to the dtexec not finding the dtsx file. Ensure you have an explicit path (C:\a\b\c\package.dtsx) to the file and not a relative one (.\package.dtsx)

Comment: Both paths are explicit.  Moreover, when I run this package string from command prompt, it works fine!!